# Storing intermediate system states as temporary file or string? (for undo/redo)

Tags: algorithm, user-interface, graphics, storage

I have a graphics system in which user can draw/edit some basic shapes like lines, beziers etc.

At any instance I have information with me, which I can save to later reproduce the scene as it is.

To implement the undo-redo functionality I plan to save this information when there is a change in the scene (Like move/draw actions), and later reproduce this.

I already have function to export this information in a custom format as a file.

I was wondering if it would be a good idea to store the intermediate stages of my drawings as series of temp files or I should store this information as a string list.

Are there advantages/disadvantages of one of these technique over other ?

What is the general trend people follow in graphics tools ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classical approach is described in the "Design Patterns" from the gang of four. Basically, you would implement a Command class, and derive it into a MoveCommand, RotateCommand,... Each instance stores the necessary information to execute that command (so for instance the deltax and deltay when you move an element). Once the command has been executed, you store it on an undo queue. When the user selects 'undo', you call another primitive undo() on the command instance, which basically does the opposite (so it would move by -deltax and -deltay in our case). This can be implemented for any command.

While this approach works fine in practice and solves a large number of issues, my own experience is that it also makes for a fragile undo/redo queue, since as soon as one of the commands doesn't handle 'undo' correctly (or at all), there is no way to undo any further.

Your proposal with capturing the state of the drawing at each step will require much more memory. In exchange, you do not need to implement the Command class at all to make sure that everything can be undone.

Comment: Or do what many version control systems do, store forward-only changes (ie. the commands you describe), but every so often store a snapshot. To undo you need to roll back to the previous snapshot then redo every command following it except the one you want to undo. You could combine these methods to have flexibility even if one or two commands doesn't/can't implement undo.